# Deploying Laravel Project to subfolder on Hostinger

Tags: laravel, deployment, scripting, hosting

I just deployed my laravel project to hostinger but all the scripts don't load files from public folder

```
    <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/fonts/fontawesome/all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/chartjs.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/camerajs.js"></script>
```

I tried to add public_path() to my scripts tags but it still leads to 404 page

Answer (score 1):

It would be more accurate to use `asset()` helper instead of `public_path()` as this will give you the `fully qualified path` not the `URL path`.

You can take a look at this [Laravel Helper](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-public-path).

Comment: Thank you that's it, I needed to use asset() helper function to have a valid path